# How do i calculate the displacement of a certain bone

Tags: drivers, displacement, mathematics

I'm trying to simulate the mechanism of the differential gear box using only math but, to do this i need to drive the weel rotation using a guide bone with a child of constraint targeting the root. My question is how can i calculate the y axis displacement of that bone. I have already try using the guide y location but wen the root does a loop on is path the rotation changes direction 2 times and it shouldnt because the movement  has a direction [image]![this is the driver][image: this is one of the 2 guides, the center bone is the rot bone][image: this is the test curve. When gets to the loop the y position of the bones decrease and thats the main problem. I don need the y position only a local Y displacement]

Comment: a screenshot describing what you do would really help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+take+a+computer+screenshot